# why skype installs only older version on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, skype

I installed skype and its working fine except that its an odl version and dont have option for video call at all. Also tried to update but when it opens to install it offers to install older version. Says "an older version of skype is available in your normal software channels" How to install new version of skype?? please help..

Comment: How did you install skype?

Comment: Which version did you install? You can find out with the command `dpkg-query -W skype`

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall existing skype application using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge skype
```

remove or rename the hidden ~/.Skype folder, this were all you subscription data are stored, use this command:

```
mv .Skype .Skype.bak
```

Then double-click on the downloaded .deb file to open it in the Ubuntu Software Center and install it like any other software.

Afterwards, also run the following command in the terminal to ensure that support for the indicator menu is available:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```